# One thread not stopping other . Even with volatile variable

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am test a scenario to use volatile variable to stop one running thread from another.
I wonder why its not working. Where is the problem?
My code is:

```
public class StoppableTask extends Thread {
    private  volatile boolean pleaseStop;

    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Running..");
       while (!pleaseStop) {
           System.out.println("Working...");
       }
    }
    public void tellMeToStop() {
        pleaseStop = true;
    }
}

public class Stopper extends Thread {
    StoppableTask t ; 

    public Stopper(StoppableTask t){
        this.t=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Ok..running too..");
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting..");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t.tellMeToStop();
        System.out.println("Done Waiting..");
    }

    public class QuickTest{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        StoppableTask t = new StoppableTask();
        Stopper s = new Stopper(t);
        t.start();
        s.start();

    }
 }
```

Comment: Strange!! After Gray solution it worked fine. But even if I take away volatile keyword for pleaseStop variable still the program keep  working fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your program is printing so much output to the terminal that it is blocking waiting for the output to be displayed.  It looks like it is not stopping but really it will.  You just need to wait... for a *long* time...

You should put a `Thread.sleep(100);` inside of of the `while()` spin loop in `StoppableTask.run()` to slow down that output.  Another way to do it is to remove the `System.out` and just increment a counter or something.

I just tried it and your program finishes in 5 seconds as expected:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running..");
    while (!pleaseStop) {
        // System.out.println("Working...");
    }
    System.out.println("Stopped task Done");
}
```

Comment: @Gray  You are right. I noticed that too.  But as real work is supposed to be done in while..loop which i simulated by system.out.Print(); And as you mentioned  I tried putting the counter and it's not giving right result.                             public class StoppableTask extends Thread {
  private  volatile boolean pleaseStop;
  private int x = 1;
  public void run() {
   System.out.println("Running..");
    while (!pleaseStop) {
     x++;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
  }
  public void tellMeToStop() {
    pleaseStop = true;
  }
}
  displays -1311527009 !!!

Comment: Real work is fine but `System.out` is just IO spew that will buffer and delay the program exit.

Comment: When you say "not giving right result" what do you mean @supernova?

Comment: @Gray  Please see my code in comments. I am unable to format it in the right way in edit window properly.

Comment: It displays a negative number because you overflowed it @supernova.  It did more than 2 _billion_ increments which overflowed the integer causing it to go negative.  Try switching it to a `long` instead.

Comment: @Gray  Perfect...its working now!! I used long. I'll select this as right answer but still didn't understood what do you mean by IO Spew? Please leave short comment on that if you deem suitable as that's in context.

Comment: I've edited my post.  Spewing output just means printing a lot of output to the screen.  At some point the screen cannot keep up and blocks the program.

Comment: Strange!! Even if I take away volatile keyword for pleaseStop variable still the program working fine!

Comment: `volatile` _ensures_ that you get the most updated value.  That doesn't mean that the program won't work without it.  When you do `System.out...` you are calling `synchronized` which updates the `pleaseStop` value as well.  But that can't be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct.
When working with threads i suggest you to use log4j instead of system.out.println.Configure the log4j to send output to a file.

You can search your string-pattern in a file. Its easy to analyse.